# Creating Servlet for each request

Tags: servlets, thread-safety

I think that for every request , container will create 1 servlet instance and will spawn multiple threads for every request. But is it possible to create particular servlet instance for every request instead of creating threads.

Comment: Any suggestions please.?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible if the servlet container's implementation conforms to the Java servlet specification.  (All major application servers do.)  You can use class (static) variables and methods to maintain state between invocations but I don't see any compulsion to do this (aside from academic purposes).